# Javascript not working on mobile browsers

Tags: android, jquery

I have a website that I've just created that has a jquery-ui slider bar link removed

The slider bar doesn't seems to work properly on my phone which is an android - it could affect other mobile browsers too.

Is there a way of fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you have to use jquery mobile and fix it yourself by making a mobile version, but thats no my area so i can't be sure

Comment: @Baadshah - thanks - i'm not a coder, or designer, so thats appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had a look on my phone and it also doesn't work. However, I have noticed in the past that other JavaScript items (on other sites) also don't work, so I don't think it's a specific problem with your site.

In terms of a workaround, you could check the viewer's user agent and display a different selection method if they're on a phone.

Comment: I'm in just doing a none javascript version at the moment. I suppose that will suffice until I can resolve it properly. Good idea though.